# Local Storage Keeps Deleting JWT Token on Refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, local-storage

For some odd reason, I'm having an issue with LocalStorage deleting my JWT token on refresh or when I open a new tab. The weird thing, is that the JWT token isn't deleted on my local dev server, only when I compile and push to heroku for the build version.

In my App.js I store the token:

```
// Check for token
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    //console.log('Logging user out');

    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
  }
}
```

I only clear the token when it's expired after an hour or the user chooses to log out. If I'm on the same tab, I can navigate to different pages and the token won't be removed. Only when I refresh the page or open the same window in a different tab it'll delete the localStorage JWT token and then force me to log back in?

// Edit:
I've checked the localStorage.jwtToken, it's getting the token properly. The issue is the setAuthToken function. For whatever reason, it's not seeing the token and instantly failing the conditional statement, and then deleting the authorization header.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = token => {
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
        // Apply to every request
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    } else {
        // Delete Auth Header
        console.log('Deleting auth header');
        // It's breaking here
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    }
}

export default setAuthToken;
```

Comment: `localStorage.jwtToken` looks unusual. `localStorage` has different [methods and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage#methods).

Comment: I've had it that way for 2 years and haven't had an issue. I use axios to set the auth token in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Solved. My computer's clock was updated by itself somehow overnight and it was instantly logging me out after checking to see if an hour had elapsed (which it did cause of the hour difference in my PC's settings).